# Logical AND error in java. Not able to do binary AND

Tags: java, data-structures, compiler-errors, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am new to java and I am learning bitwise operators. When I run the below code it throws an error. I don't know what is the mistake. I replaced `&&` by `&` it still gives an error.

```
class Main{
    
    public static void main(String []args){

      int n=5, k=3;
        if (n && (1<<(k-1)!=0))  //THIS LINE GIVING ERROR
            System.out.println("Mahima! bit is set");
        else
            System.out.println("Mahima!  bit is not set");
        
    
    }
}
```

Below is the error.

```
  Line 6: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&&' [in Main.java]
            if (n && (1<<(k-1)!=0))
                  ^
      first type:  int
      second type: boolean
```

When I use a single & I get the following error

```
Line 6: error: bad operand types for binary operator '&' [in Main.java]
        if (n & (1<<(k-1)!=0))  //THIS LINE GIVING ERROR
              ^
  first type:  int
  second type: boolean
```

Comment: People who downvote don't get notified of comments, so I doubt they'll see this and explain if they didn't originally. However calling them a loser isn't really a great way to start a conversation.

Comment: You have a point Henry. ya, I should be careful with my words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are right to change the `&&` operator to `&`.
`&&` is the **logical and** operator. It takes two `boolean`s and returns a `boolean`.
`&` is the **bitwise and** operator. It takes two `int`s and returns an `int`.

After changing `&&` to `&`, you'll have to add some parenthesis, though, since `!=` has a higher precedence than `&`:

```java
if ((n & (1<<(k-1))) !=0)
    System.out.println("Mahima! bit is set");
else
    System.out.println("Mahima!  bit is not set");
```